# PHP Application Desktop Installer (Not Setup Wizard)

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, laravel, macos

Is there any software I can use or native way of taking a PHP application (i.e. Laravel/WordPress), combining it with an HTTP server & MySQL server and packaging it up into a Windows/OSX installer?

The way I envision it working is, basically just like a XAMPP installer which already has the application in the project root and starts on boot.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: Can't give too much away. Ultimately, it just needs to be a web application that runs on a users machine. Needs to be usable in places where there is no internet. PWA is not a good enough option because sometimes they only connect to the internet once every month.

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a virtual server. You could use something like Vagrant or Docker to package up your application but this places a taller order on your end user to be savy enough to install/run it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about going that route but there'd be too many setup steps for this. Especially, as you say, for the non-technical users.

Comment: Have you considered portable virtualbox, or maybe docker?

Comment: How would Docker help in this situation? I could use VirtualBox and have it forward ports to the client machine, right? That's a possibility, but what's the possibility with Docker?

Comment: I feel you may have to go down the path of making your own solution stack.